# iptables and logs

Tags: iptables, ipset

Suppose I add an IP to iptables blocking for exim, dovecot and FTP and this IP visits my server again.

Is there any log of this visit so I can confirm the IP was trying to reach the server again but was blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
```

Comment: Doesn't this log everything? This very same command on my server made it unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

If you block a specific IP address (or net) you can view the hit count of the blocking rule via `iptables -L -vn`. If the counters for packets and bytes increase, the IP address/net has visited again.

If you need the information logged you can use the LOG target in iptables:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21,25,143 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: "
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21,25,143 -j DROP
```

The first line logs the connection attempt (to syslog or whatever you have configured) prefixing it with "iptables: " so you can grep more easily or have the output redirected by syslog to a special iptables.log for example. A LOG-jump always returns to the chain where the connection attempt is now dropped by the second rule.

Also see @sputnick's answer for additionally rate limiting those log entries to prevent logspam.